# How to save out multiple layered PSD language versions?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, automation, batch-processing

I have 14 display ad PSD files. Each file has approximately 15 design solutions (layers), divided into 3 style types. Each of these layers needs to be saved out 5 times for different language versions.

[image: language 2]

[image: language 1]

I need a quick way to batch save out the layers (but only specific layers) not all. Currently I go through this process:
1. Turn on the layers I need (depending on language and style)
2. shift-alt-cmd to save for web
3. Save file e.g. **Occasion**_300_250_inline_rectangle_**A**_FR.jpg I change the file name from A to B, B to C etc..
4.  Repeat.

Comment: Have you tried to use layer comps? It simplifies the layer selection process at least

Answer (score 0):

I would use Data merge Option in Photoshop. I understand that you already did the job of creating extra layers but for the speed sake it would be faster to put the names in the separate file.

I think you can set existing layers as data sets and then use batch to export them.